Solarization Spectrum
I'm looking to better understand the relation between the spectrum of the light which induces solarization in glass and the spectrum of the induced absorption.
More specifically, I'm interested in understanding whether irradiating some glass material with laser light (which has a narrow spectrum) would induce a similarly narrow absorption spectrum.

https://doi.org/10.1117/12.2248317 would suggest that the answer is no (if anything, the spectrum seems broader)
